# Why can't I findNone of EvernoteAPI?

Tags: python, evernote

I get this Exception when I called findNoteMetaData() with access_token by OAuth Sequence at Evernote Sandbox:

```
evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMUserException:EDAMUserException(errorCode=3, parameter='authenticationToken')
```

(I can get_note_store() and listNotebooks().)

I think errorCode=3 is PERMISSION_DENIED.

I asked to want "get notes" permission when I sent "Activation Request" via the page:
https://dev.evernote.com/support/

And I got the mail "We have activated your API key..." at Oct. 2.

Was my request wrong?
(Shoud I ask Evernote Support Team for Full Access permission?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Basic access, you can't read notes. See the table on this [page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/permissions.php).

Comment: I get Full access via the Activate API Key page. Thank you.